# Find string between two other strings within a series

Tags: regex

Sorry about the ambiguous title, as I couldn't think of how to articulate the question.

I have a CSV file that has hundreds of lines, with thousands of LDAP distinquished names.  One of the sample lines could look like:

```
CN=John Doe,OU=Miami,DC=contoso,DC=com; CN=Spamela Anderson,OU=Los Angeles,DC=contoso,DC=com; CN=Cosmo Kramer,OU=Subfolder,OU=Subfolder,OU=ParentFolder,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=com; CN=Bob Barker,DC=contoso,DC=com
CN=Luke Skywalker,OU=Tattoine,DC=contoso,DC=com; CN=Brad Pitt,OU=Hollywood,DC=contoso,DC=com; CN=Mickey Mouse,OU=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com
CN=Ted Nugent,OU=Houston,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=com; CN=Carl Sagan,DC=Uranus,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

I'd like to remove any distinguished name that is in the `FABRIKAM.COM` domain `(dc=fabrikam,dc=com)`.  In the sample, I'd like to strip out:

```
;CN=Cosmo Kramer,OU=Subfolder,OU=Subfolder,OU=ParentFolder,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=com
```

I've tried to use:

```
CN=(.*)?,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

But this finds the first occurrence of "CN=" from the *beginning* of the line until an occurrence of "DC=fabrikam,dc=com" (which would also include John Doe and Spamela Anderson, in my sample).

Is there a way to find the ***first occurrence*** of "CN=" to the ***left*** of "DC=fabrikam,DC=com" as the boundary?

(I use either Notepad++ or Programmer's Notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that `;` never appears in the values and is only used for delimiting different records, then you can use this:

```
CN=[^;]*,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

Note that the regex above may grab the match from multiple lines.

This is a quick fix, if the file uses `\n` to separate the lines:

```
CN=[^;\n]*,DC=fabrikam,DC=com
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  One weirdness is that if the fabrikam DN occurs at the beginning of a line, the search also grabs the last occurrence of "CN=" from the previous line.  Not a big deal as I can hopefully manually edit those.  But for my own knowledge, is there a way to prevent the search from crossing newlines or carriage returns?

Comment: @BHall: That is one case that I expect this to fail. Can you edit your question to include more test data?

Comment: Original question updated, but I see that you've already fixed it!  Thanks for your help, @nhahtdh!

Comment: @BHall: Note that the fix may not work if your file uses something other than `\n` to separate the lines. We normally use `\n` (Windows or Linux, Windows uses `\r\n`, but there is still `\n` in there), but there are other Unicode characters which are also used for separating lines.